# Display data from database in a Table codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I want to display information I retrieved from MySQL database into a table. I can see the JSON result in my console but I need it displayed in my app. Here is a part of my code:

```
byte[] data = cr.getResponseData();

Map response = (Stock.ParseJsonObject(data));

Stock.killNetworkAccess();
java.util.List statementResult = (java.util.List) response.get("StatementResult");
System.out.println("Statement Result:" + statementResult);

for (Object saveResult1 : statementResult) {
    Map tempHash = (Map) saveResult1;
    System.out.println(tempHash);
    String result = tempHash.get("Status").toString();
    String sellerName = tempHash.get("SellerName").toString();
    String stockName = tempHash.get("StockName").toString();
    if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
    // System.out.print("Success");
    System.out.println(stockName); //this works: I can see the list of stock names from my database

    String[] columnNames = { "Seller's Name", "Stock Name", "Unit", "Price" };
    Object[] dat = { sellerName, stockName };

    Table tb = new Table(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, (Object[][]) dat, false));
    allrec.addComponent(tb);
}

}
```

The console shows this ->>>>>>

```
Statement Result:[{ID=1, SellerName=, StockName=Seven UP, Unit=23, Price=1, TimeCreated=0000-00-00 00:00:00, Status=Ok}, {ID=2, SellerName=, StockName=Seven UP, Unit=23, Price=1, TimeCreated=0000-00-00 00:00:00, Status=Ok}, {ID=3, SellerName=, StockName=Wallmart, Unit=76, Price=34, TimeCreated=0000-00-00 00:00:00, Status=Ok}, {ID=5, SellerName=, StockName=Africa Insurance, Unit=3, Price=23, TimeCreated=0000-00-00 00:00:00, Status=Ok}
{ID=1, SellerName=, StockName=Seven UP, Unit=23, Price=1, TimeCreated=0000-00-00 00:00:00, Status=Ok}
Seven UP
```

That shows the data is being retrieved from the database. However, when I try to get it in a table I get this error dialog that says:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to Ljava.lang.Object]
```

I am sure my error is somewhere here: ->>>>

```
String[] columnNames = { "Seller's Name", "Stock Name", "Unit", "Price" };
Object[] dat = { sellerName, stockName };
Table tb = new Table(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, (Object[][]) dat, false));
```

I have these in another class called Stock:

```
public static Map ParseJsonObject(byte[] data) {
    try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Map response = parser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), "UTF-8"));
        return response;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    }
    return null;
}

public static void killNetworkAccess() {
    NetworkManager.getInstance().shutdown();
}
```

Can someone please help me out? Thank you.

Comment: The question should be about the exception not about your ultimate goal. Either way we need a stack trace to help you. Notice that you shouldn't use shutdown() on the network manager.

Comment: Okay, I was getting this exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to Ljava.lang.Object]
I explained all that so that help could come easily.

Comment: You need to provide a stack trace. It shows the method lines that call into the code that triggers the exception. If you catch the exception use printStackTrace or Log.e to get the stack.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Object;
 at com.grace.stock.AccStatement$1.run(AccStatement.java:154)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
That is the stack trace

Comment: You are casting incorrectly on line 154 of AccStatement.java

Comment: yes. I know. I just do not know how to do it correctly. I have tried casting in different ways I know of but unsuccessfully. Can someone please help out?

Answer (score 0):

Convert this:

```
Object[] dat = { sellerName, stockName };

Table tb = new Table(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, (Object[][]) dat, false));
```

To this:

```
Object[][] dat = { 
       {sellerName, stockName}
};
Table tb = new Table(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, dat, false));
```

Notice the extra brackets for the Object indicating a 2D array and the two extra curly brackets indicating another curly array.

If you think of a row as an array (set of elements) then a table is effectively an array of arrays (where every array represents a row).

Casting is strict in Java so you need to create the right type of object to begin with which is good since it saves you from trouble down the road.